# Postgresql data calculation

Tags: postgresql, common-table-expression, recursive-query

Im trying to do some calculations using postgres, but no sucess so far. My query goes something like this:

`select ....,
(select json_agg(data_table)
from (..... HERE GOES DE RESULT OF THE CALCULATION + a lot of business and data.... ) as data_table)
from foo`

So i gonna exemplify with a table:

`create temp table tbdata (id smallint, parent_id smallint, value numeric(25,2));
insert into tbdata values(1, null, 100), (2, 1, 50), (3, 1, 49), (4, 3, 20), (5, 3, 29);
select * from tbdata;`

I need to calculate the difference between the sum of the siblings and the parent value. Example:

- ID 2(50) + ID 3(49) = 99
- ID 1(parent) = 100

so i need to add 1 to any of the childs (lets say 3), the result gonna be:

- ID 2(50) + ID 3(49 + 1) = 100
- ID 1(parent) = 100

After that, my ID3 have changed, so i need to update any of his childs:

- ID 4(20) + ID 5(29) = 49
- ID 3(parent) = 50

then again, updating value of ID 5 with the difference (50 - 49)

- ID 4(20) + ID 5(29 + 1) = 50
- ID 3(parent) = 50

I tried using recursive queries, windows function, and cte, but i always stuck in something. I was able to do using a function with a loop, but i dont want to do that.

Theres any way i can do it with a single SQL?

Comment: Do you want to write a `SELECT` query or an `UPDATE` statement? It's not really clear what you mean by "I need to update".

Comment: "i need to update any of his childs*" - not any. How do you want to decide which particular one is supposed to get adjusted?

Comment: im writing a select, i meant update the result value. My decision gonna be biggest or lower value, havent decided yet. In fact, the query suppose to solve decimals places rounds, like 10/ 3 = 3.33 + 3.33 + 3.34.